# Predict moon shape clusters with Keras NN: why stays my model non-linear?

Tags: neural-networks

I first did this tutorial to understand NN:

http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/implementing-a-neural-network-from-scratch/

Now I try to rebuild it with Keras. This is the code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=X.shape[1], init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dense(2, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

y_dummy = to_categorical(y, 2)
model.fit(X, y_dummy, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=50)

plot_decision_boundary(lambda x: model.predict_classes(x))
```

It fails however defining a non-linear decision boundary, ref image.

What is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct, I needed however a lot more epochs. Depending on the optimisation algorithm, the optimisation can be stuck in a local minima or a swamp, ref graph.[image]